# How to get Child Span Text from Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to this and I have been trying to figure out how to get child span text from the option I select. I am trying to get the text from class: payment-percent and payment-flat from the selected option. Thank you really appreciate it.

```
<div>
    <select name="payment-method">
        <option value="paypal"><span class="payment-percent">2.9</span>% + <span class="payment-flat">0.30</span></option>
        <option value="stripe"><span class="payment-percent">3.9</span>% + <span class="payment-flat">0.60</span></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html tag may not work inside the options. Instead you can get the selected text using pseudo selector `:selected` and split it by the delimiter `+`. This will give an array with 2 elements. You can use the `index` to get the elements

```js
$('#payment-method').on('change', function() {
  let selectedText = ($(this).find(":selected").text()).trim().split('+');
  console.log(selectedText[0], selectedText[1]);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="payment-method" id='payment-method'>
    <option value="paypal"><span class="payment-percent">2.9</span>% + <span class="payment-flat">0.30</span></option>
    <option value="stripe"><span class="payment-percent">3.9</span>% + <span class="payment-flat">0.60</span></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should `trim()` each value after `split()`

Answer (score 1):

I have a vanilla JavaScript solution (aka no JQuery). This can be easily achieved. On your html, make the following changes:

```
<div>
  <select name="payment-method" id="select-payment" onChange="selectOption(this);">
    <option value="paypal"><span class="payment-percent">2.9</span>% + <span class="payment-flat">0.30</span></option>
    <option value="stripe"><span class="payment-percent">3.9</span>% + <span class="payment-flat">0.60</span></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

And on your javascript file,

```
function selectOption(select) {
  console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, try something like this:

```
$("select[name=payment-method] option:selected").text();
```

In vanilla.js:

```
let selectbox=document.querySelector("select[name='payment-method']");
var text=selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
try {
  var selectedOption = document.getElementsById('payment-method').selectedOptions
  var value = selectedOption && selectedOption[0].text
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Element not found')
}
```